# Stencil.js Jest: mock FileReader 'not defined' unless use window.FileReader

Tags: javascript, jestjs, stenciljs

I have a `util.ts` module with a utility class that reads files after an `input` has uploaded them:

```js
// utils/utils.ts

export class JsonFileProcessor {

   process(files) {
     // ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined
     const reader = new FileReader();
   }
}
```

In my `utils.spec.ts` I mock the `window.FileReader` (which is undefined up to this point)

```js
import { JsonFileProcessor } from "./utils";

describe("JsonFileProcessor", () => {

 it("processes the files", () => {
   // createMockFileReader returns a `class MockFileReader`
   // that replicates the methods of FileReader
   window.FileReader = createMockFileReader(files)
   const processor = new JsonFileProcessor();
   processor.process(someFiles);
```

I get an error in the JsonFileProcessor.process method `ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined`, but if I replace `new FileReader()` with `new window.FileReader()` it works

I've been stuck on this for ages now! I'm using Stencil.js and running the Jest setup that it comes with. There are other `window` properties that are available (as I've debugged it and console.log'd it)

I know I have to mock FileReader myself, but I'm stumped as to why the util class isn't finding the mocked class unless I specifically use `new window.FileReader()`

Comment: Not sure but could it be related to order of imports? Maybe you need to add the mock before importing your util.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Stencil's `jest` setup does not include `jsdom`. Stencil uses a slimmed down version of **Puppeteer** for unit tests - the `window` and `document` properties of which can be accessed via the `page` object returned from Stencil's `newSpecPage()`

As my tests are running without `newSpecPage` I needed to use the `global` object instead e.g. `global.FileReader = createMockFileReader(files)`

Comment: Can you please explain further you answer?